# Show the following grammar is ambiguous

Tags: grammar, ambiguous-grammar

I'm trying to identify a sentence that can produce more than one derivation tree. Also provide two different trees from the sentence

```
<S> = <A>
<A> = <A> + <A> | <B> 
<B> = a | b | c
```

p.s i have a hard time figuring out the sentences

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a problem set question, so I won't give a full answer here. However, as a hint, try showing that the string `a + a + a` has two different parse trees.

Hope this helps!

Comment: were does the other a come from? i guess you replaced it form the <B>